# Remove action working on functions.php but not in a plugin. Why?

Tags: plugins, actions

I am trying to remove an action from Woothemes' Sensei plugin.

If I do on the functions.php:

```
global $woothemes_sensei;
remove_action('sensei_lesson_video', array($woothemes_sensei->frontend, 'sensei_lesson_video'));
```

I can remove the action.

But if I do the same on a plugin, I can't.

Actually, the problem is that after var_dumping $woothemes_sensei on a plugin a get NULL.

Why is that?

EDIT: Well, here is the answer. I should put the code inside a function and hooked it to `init`or `after_setup_theme`. But I found a Sensei hook, that runs before the loop (`sensei_before_main_content`). So I did:

```
    add_action('sensei_before_main_content', 'trib_s2sensei');

function trib_s2sensei() {

   global $woothemes_sensei;
   remove_action('sensei_lesson_video', array($woothemes_sensei->frontend, 'sensei_lesson_video')); 
}
```

Comment: when does the plugin add that action? what [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) do you run your code on?

Comment: I could not understand your questions. I am saying that this exactly code works on the functions.php theme file but not on a custom plugin. Is it a matter of when? Should I run this code on any wp action hook when placing it on a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include of custom code via theme is different from the including via plugin. 
It is important, that you add a hook to include your custom source inside the plugin, like `after_setup_theme`, maybe with a low priority, after the default theme init his code.

Comment: Well, it worked hooking it to `after_setup_theme`. Thanks for the suggestion. But don't you think it would be better hooking it to `init` ?

Comment: The hook is depending from the hook, there was used from the source, there you will remove.